# Diff with white spaces and different numerical precision

Tags: diff

I have two files:

$cat a.txt

```
            1
        72200
            1    1.000000000000000     
  1.109393E+01  3.670034E-01  0.000000E+00
  1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01  3.636971E-02
  1.110000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
            2    1.000000000000000     
  1.109940E+01  0.000000E+00  3.636971E-02
  1.110000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
  1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01  3.636971E-02
            3    1.000000000000000     
  1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01  3.636971E-02
  1.109153E+01  3.669239E-01  7.269964E-02
  1.109940E+01  0.000000E+00  3.636971E-02
```

$cat b.txt

```
           1
       72200
           1   1.00000000000000     
  1.109393E+01  3.670034E-01  0.000000E+00
  1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01  3.636971E-02
  1.110000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
           2   1.00000000000000     
  1.109940E+01  0.000000E+00  3.636971E-02
  1.110000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
  1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01  3.636971E-02
           3   1.00000000000000     
  1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01  3.636971E-02
  1.109153E+01  3.669239E-01  7.269964E-02
  1.109940E+01  0.000000E+00  3.636971E-02
```

The only difference between them is the positioning of some numbers, i.e. they are placed at different number of white spaces from the left and the numerical precision. I am interested up to 10^-6 precision. How could I diff the files knowing that I am only interested in up to 10^-6 precision? I have tried a few options with not much success:

1.diff -wy -W 70 a.txt b.txt

```
            1                                  1
        72200                              72200
            1    1.00000000000    |            1   1.0000000000000
  1.109393E+01  3.670034E-01          1.109393E+01  3.670034E-01  
  1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01          1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01  
  1.110000E+01  0.000000E+00          1.110000E+01  0.000000E+00  
            2    1.00000000000    |            2   1.0000000000000
  1.109940E+01  0.000000E+00          1.109940E+01  0.000000E+00  
  1.110000E+01  0.000000E+00          1.110000E+01  0.000000E+00  
  1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01          1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01  
            3    1.00000000000    |            3   1.0000000000000
  1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01          1.109333E+01  3.669835E-01  
  1.109153E+01  3.669239E-01          1.109153E+01  3.669239E-01  
  1.109940E+01  0.000000E+00          1.109940E+01  0.000000E+00
```

What can I do?